# Montgomery Ladder Algorithm running slower than it is supposed to

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, optimization, elliptic-curve

I was implementing the Montgomery ladder in python and when I tried to run it was a pretty small number it became super slow. What am I doing wrong?

```
def addPoints(xp, zp, xq, zq, xpq, zpq):
    u = (xp + zp) * (xq - zq)
    v = (xp - zp) * (xq + zq)
    w = u + v
    t = u - v
    w = w * w
    t = t * t
    X = w * zpq
    Z = t * xpq
    return X, Z

def duplicatePoint(xp, zp, b):
    u = xp + zp
    v = xp - zp
    u = u * u
    v = v * v
    uv = u - v
    t = b * uv + v
    x2p = u * v
    z2p = uv * t
    return x2p, z2p

def montgomeryLadder(k, px, pz, a24):
    qx, qz = px, pz
    rx, rz = duplicatePoint(px, pz, a24)
    for i in bin(k)[3:]:
        print(i)
        if i == 1:
            qx, qz = addPoints(rx, rz, qx, qz, px, pz)
            rx, rz = duplicatePoint(rx, rz, a24)
        else:
            rx, rz = addPoints(qx, qz, rx, rz, px, pz)
            qx, qz = duplicatePoint(qx, qz, a24)

    return qx, qz
```

The algorithm is shown here: https://www.iacr.org/archive/ches2006/10/10.pdf

I know it's not supposed to run this slow because it is supposed to be one of the fastest algorithms for scalar multiplication of points on a elliptic curve. The test case I used was: 
`montgomeryLadder(80219347, 3, 2, 5)` and I am 100% sure it is not supposed to run like this.

Comment: You aren't doing any modular reductions. The ints will just keep getting bigger and bigger, and slower and slower.

Comment: So do I do the reductions on every single addition/subtraction/multiplication/division or do I just do 1 mod reduction at the end of the program?

Comment: Every single multiplication. Additions/subtractions you can typically ignore.

Comment: and the code should still work the same right?

Comment: It will give you a correct answer unless you have other bugs. But you don't want it to work the *same*, because it wasn't working at all before.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @J.Doe did you try how to recover y coordinates?